# Loading multiple files

Tags: google-bigquery

The following is working as expected.

./bq --nosync load -F '^' --max_bad_record=30000 myvserv.xa one.txt ip:string,cb:string,country:string,telco_name:string, ...

1) But how to I send two csv files one.txt and two.txt in the same command?

2) I can not cat file and then pipe | to bg command ?

3) What does nosync mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Unfortunately, you can't (yet) upload two files with the same command; you'll have to run bq twice.  (If you're loading data from Google Cloud Storage, though, you can specify multiple gs:// URLs separated by commas.)
2. Nope, bq doesn't (yet) support reading upload data from stdin, though that's a great idea for a future version.
3. If you just run "bq load", bq will create a load job on the server and then poll for completion.  If you specify the --nosync flag, it will just create the load job and then exit without polling.  (If desired, you can poll for completion separately using "bq wait".)

Answer (score 0):

For 1), as Jeremy mentioned, you can't import two local files at once in the same command. However, you can start two parallel loads to the same table -- loads are atomic, and append by default, so this should do what you want and may be faster than importing both in a single job since the uploads will happen in parallel.